# Exporting contour labels to DXF

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour

I am very new in QGIS.

I imported a DEM in QGIS, I generated contours, then I have added some labels.

I have been able to export those contours in DXF but the labels haven't been exported.

How can I export the contours with labels?

Comment: What version of QGIS?

Comment: QGIS version 3.4.2

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Project > Import/Export > Export Project to DXF that will include your labels in the resulting DXF. I find a variety of issues with this methodology such as not being able to script it in the Graphical Modeller and not being able to get the labels the right size.

Here is a strategy that works reasonably well - I recommend using the graphical modeller to do this especially if you need to do it more than once.  You can also use the modeller to extract and smooth the contours as required.

The [GDAL DXF driver only supports Labels on point](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html) feature types so you need some points on the lines.

Use **Random points on lines** and control the number of points per feature using an expression like this

case when $length > 15
then 1+(toint( $length /400))
when $length < 15
then 0
end

Then you probably want the labels to be rotated to match the lines. To do this you can split the lines into short lengths, calculate the angle of the segments and then get (join) the angle for each point from the nearest line segment

Use **Split lines by maximum length** with a maximum length of 10m should be fine

Use **Refactor Fields** to create the attributes you need to join to the points
Attribute: Angle - You can calculate a line angle in a variety of ways, I used the following:

```
case when 360-(toint(line_interpolate_angle( $geometry,($length /2)  ))) <180 Then (360-(toint(line_interpolate_angle( $geometry,($length /2)  ))))-90 when 360-(toint(line_interpolate_angle( $geometry,($length /2)  ))) >180 Then ((360-(toint(line_interpolate_angle( $geometry,($length /2)  ))))-180)-90 end
```

Attribute: Length  -

```
 $length
```

Attribute: ELEV  - Get the attribute from you contours (probably ELEV)

Use **Join Attributes by Nearest** to get the rotation and elevation details from the nearest line segment

Now you have label points with information needed to create labels when exporting to DXF using GDAL2GDAL/ convert format. To create the labels you need an **OGR_STYLE** attribute which GDAL will recognise and use to create the labels. You can find full details of the style in the [Feature Style Specification Documentation](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_feature_style.html) which shows how to control things like the size, font and anchor position. At this point you can also add an attribute to specify what DXF layer the labels should be.

Use **Refactor Fields**  to create the ORG_STYLE and Layer fields

Attribute: OGR_STYLE - You can use something like the below but modify to suit how you want your labels to appear

```
'LABEL' || '(f:"ARIAL",s:2500mm,a:' ||  to_int(  "Angle") || ',t:' ||  "ELEV"  || ',p:5' || ')'
```

Attribute: Layer - Just a text string for the layer name

Use **Convert Format** to export the label points to a DXF

You will also need to use **Convert Format** to export the contour lines. You can create and use OGR_STYLE and Layer fields to control the graphics and layer of the lines in you resulting DXF. You can also use an ELEV field so your DXF contour lines will be at the specified elevation (2D polylines with a Z value) .